# Get domain with its subdomain from url

Tags: php, regex, subdomain

I'm using this function to get domain and subdomain from a string. But If string is already my expected format, it returns null

```
function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    return preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);
}

$url = "http://abc.example.com/" -> abc.example.com | OK

$url = "http://www.example.com/" -> example.com | OK

$url = "abc.example.com" -> FAILS!
```

Comment: `www` is a subdomain too.

Comment: I know. I want to eliminate www

Comment: But not other subdomains? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that parse_url is returning false. Check to make sure you get a response before trying to use it otherwise `$host` is empty.

```
<?php
function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    $host = (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) != '') ? parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) : $url;
    return preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);
}
echo getDomainFromUrl("http://abc.example.com/") . "\n";
echo getDomainFromUrl("http://www.example.com/") . "\n";
echo getDomainFromUrl("abc.example.com");
```

Output:

> abc.example.com
>  
>   example.com
>   abc.example.com

Answer (score 3):

That is because `abc.example.com` is not a `PHP_URL_HOST` so you need to first check that it is one first. So you should do something simple like this, where if the url is doesn't have a protocol -> add it:

```
function addhttp($url) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    return $url;
}

function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if($host){
        return preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);
    }else{
        //not a url with protocol
        $url = addhttp($url); //add protocol
        return getDomainFromUrl($url); //run function again.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think schlaus' answer is the best!

Comment: @Maximilian: schlaus' way will fail if the url has a user/pass part.

Comment: @Maximilian: the recursion is a little ugly, you can write the same in a single function without recursion. example: https://eval.in/355445

Comment: That is nice!! Yeah I realised mine was very ugly!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for the heads up, I updated my solution. It now handles ports as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure regex solution:

```
function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    if (preg_match('/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:[^@]*@)|(?:[^:]*:[^@]*@))?(?:www\.)?([^\/:]+)/', $url, $parts)) {
        return $parts[1];
    }
    return false; // or maybe '', depending on what you need
}

getDomainFromUrl("http://abc.example.com/"); // abc.example.com

getDomainFromUrl("http://www.example.com/"); // example.com

getDomainFromUrl("abc.example.com");         // abc.example.com

getDomainFromUrl("username@abc.example.com"); // abc.example.com

getDomainFromUrl("https://username:password@abc.example.com"); // abc.example.com

getDomainFromUrl("https://username:password@abc.example.com:123"); // abc.example.com
```

You can try it here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f0343bbb68b190bffff5d568470681c00b0c45c

In case you want to know more about the regex:

```
^                 matching must start from the beginning on the string
(?:https?:\/\/)?  an optional, non-capturing group that matches http:// and https://

(?:(?:[^@]*@)|(?:[^:]*:[^@]*@))?
                  an optional, non-capturing group that matches either *@ or *:*@ where * is any character
(?:www\.)?        an optional, non-capturing group that matches www.
([^\/:]+)          a capturing group that matches anything up until a '/', a ':', or the end of the string
```

Comment: It is more waterproof now, be careful, you have removed the *start of the string* anchor in your edit.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Sigh, there's always something isn't there? :D Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function doesn't work with relative URLs. You can test if the sheme is present, and if not add the default one:

```
if ( !preg_match( '/^([^\:]+)\:\/\//', $url ) ) $url = 'http://' . $url;
```